# Hex to Decimal converter

Tags: java, algorithm, number-systems

Any feedback is welcome:

```
public class HexToDecimal {

    static String hexRep = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(HexToDecimal.hexToDecimal("AB"));
    }

    public static int hexToDecimal(String hex) {

        int counter = hex.length()-1;
        int sum = 0;

        for (char c:hex.toCharArray()) {
            int i = hexRep.indexOf(c);
            sum = (int) (sum + (Math.pow(16,counter))*i);
            counter--;
        }

        return sum;
    }

}
```

Comment: I presume this is an exercise or homework, because there are built-in methods to do this.

Comment: @BartKiers I'd be interested to hear your answer with the built-in answer, because I didn't use a built-in in my current project. No external libraries allowed, mind you. ... although mine was converting a hex string to a regular string... Which is different from converting a hex string to a int value, I guess?

Comment: @BartKiers I am too old for homeworks.

Comment: I don't know. I mean, lots of adults/working people do some courses in the evening. It could be homework and the teacher said you couldn't use `Integer.valueOf("AB", 16)` :)

Comment: The code doesn't fulfil its specifications because it doesn't return a decimal number, it returns an int, which is a *binary* representation of the number. People often confuse this but it's nevertheless wrong. To return a decimal representation you'd need to either return an array of decimal digits or a string of decimal digits, just like your input is a string of hexadecimal digits.

Comment: @KonradRudolph An array of decimal digits? You mean an array of ints?

Comment: @KorayTugay Doesn’t really matter how you represent the digits. `ints` would of course be an obvious way.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry what is the difference then? An array of ints is a decimal but an int itself is not?

Comment: @KorayTugay The difference is that you store the *decimal digits* **indidually**. At the moment you are simply not returning a decimal number, full stop. When you return an array or a string of decimal digits it doesn’t matter how the digits themselves are stored, what matters (for the definition of a decimal number) is that the number consists of decimal digits.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry man I do not agree at all.. Returning an array of ints or Strings would not be any more decimal.

Comment: @KorayTugay Well it’s not about agreeing, you’re simply factually wrong. The concept of [digital number representation](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/NumSys.html) is quite well-defined. What your function does is *not* a conversion to a decimal representation. In order to get a decimal representation, you need to get decimal digits. Your function clearly doesn’t produce decimal digits. End of story. The decimal digits are produced by `System.out.println` in your code, not by your function.

Comment: @KonradRudolph what you are suggesting is not decimals either. I am returning number of bits and if I tell you that it must be interpreted so.. What you are suggesting is no idfferent.A computer that has no sense of ASCII will not return or store decimals either. All we have is binary. Returning the ASCII binary for the character 2 is no more decimal then what I do. End of story.

Comment: @KorayTugay Yes it is. Very different. You seem to have a fundamental roadblock in understanding the difference between a value and its representation. Maybe this piece of code can help you. Notice that this code has four methods: `fromDec`, `fromHex`, `toDec` and `toHex`, and to show that you have to treat decimal and hexadecimal representations in the same way, they call the same two conversion routines: `fromBaseRepresentation` and `toBaseRepresentation`. Decimals simply don’t have special status, and `int` is no more decimal than hex: https://gist.github.com/klmr/2722423aa651a44cf0d2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java's `Integer` class has a built-in method to parse a hex number (`string`) into an `int`:

```
Integer.valueOf("AB", 16)
```

W.R.T. your code, here are some observations:

- `hexRep` should be `final`
- Ideally your method should also accept lower-case text (just call `toUpperCase()` on the string)
- Include some unit tests perhaps?
- I wouldn't put that single method in a class of its own. More appropriate would be to put it in a more general utility class

Answer (score 9):

```
static String hexRep = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

Imagine if I put some code in the same package and did `HexToDecimal.hexRep = "";` Now I broke your program!

This one needs to be `private static final`

---

Your `hexToDecimal` method is not checking for invalid input. Calling `hexToDecimal("7G")` causes incorrect results, without any kind of warning or indication that an error occurred. Throwing an exception is the least you can do! An exception should probably also be thrown if it goes outside the valid `int` range.

Also, the string should be converted to uppercase inside the method to also support strings like `"7a8d"`.

Answer (score 7):

To get a normal integer from a hex string you can use the built-in [Integer.parseInt(String, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) which simplifies things to `Integer.parseInt("AB", 16);`

The actual parsing code can be simplified by knowing that `"AB"*16 == "AB0"` this allows you to do away with the pow operation:

```
for (char c:hex.toCharArray()) {
    int i = hexRep.indexOf(c);
    sum = sum*16 + i;
}
```

Comment: `sum * 16` can be replaced with `sum << 4`

Comment: @Pimgd that tends to be overkill and unreadable for new programmers, java will do that for you soon enough.

Answer (score 5):

### Naming

Strictly speaking, your method does not convert the hex string into decimal.  Rather, it parses the hex string as an integer.  It's [`PrintWriter.println(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(int)) that actually converts it to base-10 notation.  Until then, it's just a signed 32-bit number, not in any particular base.  (Well, the Java Language Specification doesn't say so, but you know that your computer works in base 2.)

Therefore, if you wanted to reinvent the wheel, you should rename your function to

```
public static int fromHex(String hex)
```

### Bugs

You don't do any validation, so any unexpected characters would be interpreted as a -1 hexdigit, since that's how `String.indexOf()` behaves.  There are a number of reasonable behaviours in the face of unexpected input, but this is one of the least expected failure modes.  (Throwing an exception would be best.)  Note that lowercase a-f are unsupported, and thus fail in that manner.